# Unexpected character '@' when making a declaring App.vu as component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I scaffolded and app using vue CLI v3.0.3

so I have an App.vue that looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="less">
```

I need to import a component that will wrap `<router-view>` with a container.

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Container as MyContainer } from "@mylib/container";

@Component({
  components: {
    MyContainer
  }
})
export default class App extends Vue {}
```

When I build I get an error

> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (15:0) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Do I need to tell vue that App.vue is a component?

Comment: Did you activate the `--experimentalDecorators` flag? https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component#usage

Comment: @BennettDams I have the option set to true in tsconfig.json

Comment: and I added the decorators legacy plugin to babel.rc

Comment: Did you import component to use the annotation correctly  (`import { Component } from "vue-property-decorator";`?

Comment: yes. In another project it was from 'vue-class-component'

Comment: If you used vue-cli to generate a TypeScript project (and with the class-syntax option), you shouldn't need to add any Babel plugins or other config changes to use the class-syntax for components. The default `HelloWorld.vue` even uses `@Component`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create the project with CLI and didn't select to install "babel".

Trying to add it by hand didn't work so I re-created the project and selected "babel", then the decorators worked.